# Codeigniter error after upgrade: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$ar_orderby

Tags: codeigniter

I have updated Codeigniter from 2.1 to 2.2 then to 3 and now when I run it I get this error

```
Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$ar_orderby system\core\Model.php 73
```

Here's the code in **My_Model.php**:

```
if(!count($this->db->ar_orderby)){
   $this->db->order_by($this->order_by);
}
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570610/undefined-property-error-in-codeigniter-code) and tested its answer by replacing the above code with this one

```
if(!count($this->db->order_by($this->_order_by))) {
  $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
}
```

But I get this error

```
Undefined property: Home::$_order_by system\core\Model.php 73
```

I also tried this

```
if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
    $this->db->order_by($this->orders);
}
```

But I get:

```
Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$ar_orderby
Filename: core/MY_Model.php
Line Number: 59

Message: Undefined property: Home::$orders
Filename: core/Model.php
Line Number: 73
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: did you change your config/database.php? see: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-7-update-your-config-database-php

Comment: yes changed to $query_builder = TRUE; instead of active_record

Comment: if you look into system/core/model.php at around line 73, it says: `  // Debugging note:
  // If you're here because you're getting an error message
  // saying 'Undefined Property: system/core/Model.php', it's
  // most likely a typo in your model code.`

Comment: The above code is in My_Model.php. The Model.php in the system folder I just downloaded from codeigniter repository I didn't touch it

Comment: @Vickel means a typo in My_Model - the code you have written, not the core code.

Comment: @DFriend I never said it was an error in core, just pointed out what line 73 states in comments

Comment: @Vickel Yes, that is what I was trying to tell the OP who seemed to think you accused him of messing with the core. At least that's the way I read his reply to your first comment. Just trying to back you up.

Comment: It's the original file from the old project which is My_Model.php it just triggered this issue on my localhost after the upgrade

Comment: I don't get the point of this to begin with. the code for get is pretty quick by itself. just use regular query builder and forget these "helper" type functions that do more harm than good.

Comment: Let me fully understand its usage is it used to order the result of the query asc or desc as defined by the user in the query?

Answer (score 0):

It is a change in property names that causes the problem. Starting in V3, *Active Record* (AR) was changed to *Query Builder* (QB). Along with that change, the prefix of class properties changed from "ar_" to "qb_".

Unfortunately the AR property `$ar_orderby` was public and the QB version of the same property - `$qb_orderby` - is protected so it cannot be accessed from `MY_Model`.

I don't know that there is an easy way to extend `CI_DB_query_builder` successfully due to the way it used to create the `CI_DB` class. (See line #182 of /system/database/DB.php) But adding a "getter" function to retrieve the value of `$qb_orderby` is required in order to make `if(!count($this->db->qb_orderby)){` work. The getter can only be added by extending or hacking the core class.

Comment: The first one triggers this error: Undefined property: Home::$qb_orderby system\core\Model.php 73  |  and the second one triggers this error: Fatal error: Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$qb_orderby  in application\core\MY_Model.php on line 54

Comment: On closer examination, I can see that the second variation is the one that would be able to access Query Builder. But unfortunately, the properties are protected in Query Builder where they were public in Active Record.

Comment: @PHPUser, I've changed my answer but you won't like it.